# Find last non-empty cell of a row, then copy till that cell and paste

Tags: excel, vba

VBA code which finds the last non empty cell of Row 5, copies the data till that cell of Row 5 and pastes that data as values after transposing. I tried to record a macro by copying the data but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're talking about excel vba. The below code copies from a range in sheet1 column A,  down to the last data in the row ( you can change this to be only to row 5 if you have data after 5 that you don't want to copy). Then it transposes it on to sheet2.

---

update to only go to 5

```
Sub someMacro()

Dim answerRange As Range
Dim checkBlankRange As Range
Dim lastRowInRange As Long
Dim lastcolumn As Long

Set checkBlankRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5") 'changed to 1 to 5
lastRowInRange = 5 ' default to 5
lastcolumn = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column
'or you can use line below for last column 
'lastcolumn = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Sheets("Sheet1").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For Each cell In checkBlankRange
            If cell.Value = "" Then 'first empty cell
                    lastRowInRange = cell.row 'get the row number of the empty cell
                Exit For
            End If
    Next cell

    Set answerRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastRowInRange, lastcolumn))

answerRange.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

---

if the data is always going to be in those colums you wont need alot of the code and you can just use what you had in your recorded macro - cleaned up to remove selects

```
Sub simpleVersion()

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F5").Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much James, I just want to know how do I restrict it to Row no. 5 of Column A. Because I have have alot of junk data after row no. 5 which i dnt want to copy.

Comment: Also, wen I copied ur macro and tried to run, it gave me the values of column A transposed in sheet2, But i want respective values as well

Comment: I update to do just to row 5. What do you mean respective values?

Comment: Can I please send the raw data and the output which I want ?

Comment: sure just put a screenshot in your question. so that others are able to help if i'm not. Also, it makes it wasier for people that have similar issues they are trying to work through

Comment: Well, it says u cnt add image unless u have 10 reputations, may be this site needs smething more, Can I send my sample file or screeshot somewea else ?

Comment: ah. do you know how to record a macro. You should try that and then post what you recorded. or try to explain to me more what you mean by respective values. the more detail the better. you can put it in step 1. setp 2 etc form

Comment: Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Range("A1:F5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
End Sub

Comment: Respective value means, I have data in sheet1 with column A, B, C and so on say till column "F". But I just want to copy the whole data till "RowNo. 5". Also, in my example the last column will vary with data accordingly. That is why i want to figure out what is the last non empty cell in row 5.

Comment: updated it answer the line that changed is: Set answerRange = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:F" & lastRowInRange). Did that work?

Comment: Thank you James, it worked. But one more thing the column F will not be same always. In other words, even I dont know what will be the last column in my data, as these columns are data driven. The more the data, more will be the columns. So, is there any way dat I need not to worry about what is my last column as in above example it is "F". Or do I need to always change my column name in macro?

Comment: James, what if my range changes like "Set checkBlankRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5") (in ur above code) as u said but what if I want to take the data from A15 : A20, leaving that rows in between. So that total  data is A1:A5 and A15:A20 ? Any suggestions

Comment: Hi 28300, honestly, I would think about a sheet redesign. Maybe separating out those 10 rows in the middle from that which you are reading. For example putting them on another sheet. Because it seems the model (the range(s)) and your controller (these protected cells that you don't want to copy) are too closely tied together. Or maybe if you don't want them on a different sheet move those protected cells up and keep one range. Or you could just double the code adding in another checkblankrange2 and set a different range. but that would be pretty ugly

Comment: U r correct !! I was thinking the same I mean moving those lines up and maintaining the same range, jus wanted your suggestion too !! Thanks alot